# Create sub domain configuration in IIS

Tags: windows, iis

I have a domain ABC.COM and IP 1.2.3.4
THe ABC.COm is purchased from namecheap and in the configuration it says

- A 1.2.3.4
- @ 1.2.3.4

And my server which is with IP 1.2.3.4 has a website in port 80, the question here is
1. The server uses IIS to host website, in the binding the Hostname field is empty, if I try to input ABC.COm I won't be able to access my website using ABC.com in browser saying error.
2. How do I create sub domain in my server 1.2.3.4 do I create a new website and uses a new port? for example 9123, and how do I configure subdomain.ABC.COM to connect to point to that new website?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ABC.COM should be available in the context you provided. Maybe you need to add a firewall exception for port 80. If the hostname is empty, your website will serve requests for any domain/subdomain that points to the IP configured for the website. Further more, it will serve requests for any of the server's public IPs if you configured * in the "IP Address" field. Of course you cannot have multiple websites with the same hostname (empty or not) and IP or *. That's why you will have to provide a hostname for your subdomains.
2. You don't need specific ports for your subdomains. But you need a DNS server. If you choose to install DNS role here's what you have to do after:

   - Define a forward lookup zone for your domain (primary) abc.com
   - Replace the name of your server with ns.abc.com in the default created SOA and NS records
   - Provide an A record ns (ns.abc.com) for your public IP
   - Open port 53 in your firewall
   - change nameserver for your domain to ns.abc.com
     Don't forget about propagation times. You will have to wait for this to work. Check with nslookup abc.com.
3. If you use a external DNS server for abc.com, just create A records for your subdomains to 1.2.3.4 and provide the subdomain (fully qualified test.abc.com) as a hostname when you create the website. In this onfiguration you can use either * or your public IP as "IP Address" since the hostname differs.